# Notification launched by date from sqlite db

Tags: sqlite, notifications, alarmmanager

In my app i keep date (dd-mm-yyyy) in SQLite DB, and i want to launch 1 day before that date te notification.
Am i doing something wrong that notification is not starting?

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
BHItem currentItem;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    NotificationManager mNM;
    mNM = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Return time",System.currentTimeMillis());

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(context, MainActivity.class), 0);

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, context.getText(R.string.alarm_service_label), currentItem.getItem() + " return to: " + currentItem.getReturndate(), contentIntent);
    mNM.notify(R.string.alarm_service_label, notification);
    notification.flags|= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
}
}
```

AlarmManager class
here im tring to compare current date with date from database, and if its 1 day bef

```
public class AlarmService  {

private BHItem alarmDate;
private Context context;
private PendingIntent mAlarmSender;


public AlarmService(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    mAlarmSender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class), 0);
}

public void startAlarm(){


    Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();

        Calendar myDate= Calendar.getInstance();

        try {
            Date convDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse(alarmDate.getReturndate());
            myDate.setTime(convDate);


            if (currentDate.compareTo(myDate)== 1) {
                long dd = myDate.getTimeInMillis();
                AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, dd, mAlarmSender);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
           // Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

}
}
```

Also i tried to start alarm with this, but still nothing
    public void startAlarm(){

```
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);
    long firstTime = c.getTimeInMillis();

    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, firstTime, mAlarmSender);
}
```

in Manifest i added

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"></uses-permission>
<application...
<receiver android:process=":remote" android:name="AlarmReceiver"></receiver>
```

thanks for any clues and help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested this code and onReceive is not getting fired. I order to make it work, you should set a intent filter in your receiver config in Manifest. And then use the same filter when setting the intent for your alarm. Set receiver in manifest like this:

```
<receiver
        android:name="AlarmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NOTIFY" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

And then change this code snippet:

```
mAlarmSender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class), 0);
```

To this:

```
mAlarmSender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent("android.intent.action.NOTIFY"), 0);
```

Those changed made this working on API 15. Make sure to test this solution first with short time alarm set to fire after few seconds, it's much easier to debug it this way.